# Simplification of this fourier transform signum function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, dirac-delta

Given this equation:

$$\frac{-1}{4c}[\int_{ -\infty}^{\infty}g(\varpi)Sgn(x - ct - \varpi).d\varpi -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(\varpi)Sgn(x+ct - \varpi ).d\varpi ]$$
Where sgn is the signum function, how do I reduce it to

$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(\varpi )d\varpi $$?

While I can see how the bounds changed, I am unable to see how the function within the integral simplified.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The signum function is the "sign" function. It is $+1$ if the argument is positive, $-1$ if the argument is negative and $0$ if the argument is $0$. Think of $x-ct$ as fixed, which it is for the purposes of the integral with respect to $w$. Then $\mbox{Sgn}(x-ct-w)$ is positive if $x-ct > w$ and is negative if $x-ct < w$. So divide the line into
$$++++++(x-ct)--------------$$
The above represents how the funtion is $+1$ if $w < x-ct$ and is $-1$ if $w > x-ct$. Similarly, the second function $\mbox{Sgn}(x+ct-w)$ looks like
$$----------------(x+ct)+++++$$
If you add those two, then you get what you want. However, you're subtracting the two, which makes me suspicious of a sign error in what you wrote.